# Typescript + Webpack + Node and process.env is empty

Tags: node.js, typescript, webpack

I am trying to compile my application first with TypeScript then with Webpack. I need this because my server has to be a single js file.

You can download my problem project here:

https://s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/test-bucket-alsh/untitled+folder.zip

index.ts

```
console.log(process)
console.log(process.env)
```

webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    entry: path.join(__dirname, '/index.ts'),
    mode,
    node: {
        console: true,
        global: true,
        process: true,
        __filename: true,
        __dirname: true,
        Buffer: true,
        setImmediate: true
    },
    output: {
        filename: 'index.js',
        path: __dirname
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                use: ['ts-loader']
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5", 
        "module": "commonjs",  
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "outDir": "./dist/",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "lib": [
            "es2016"
        ],
        "types": [
            "node"
        ]
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

`npx webpack && node index.js`

Results in

```
{ nextTick: [Function],
    title: 'browser',
    browser: true,
    env: {},
    argv: [],
    version: '',
    versions: {},
    on: [Function: noop],
    addListener: [Function: noop],
    once: [Function: noop],
    off: [Function: noop],
    removeListener: [Function: noop],
    removeAllListeners: [Function: noop],
    emit: [Function: noop],
    prependListener: [Function: noop],
    prependOnceListener: [Function: noop],
    listeners: [Function],
    binding: [Function],
    cwd: [Function],
    chdir: [Function],
    umask: [Function] }
{}
```

Comment: What's the contents of a transpiled `index.js`?

Comment: What is the expected result? You console.log two objects, one is process, another one is process.env, which is empty. What is wrong?

Comment: The env should be populated with my system's env, however it's empty. Say I run `MYVAR=something && npx webpack && node index.js`, `process.env.MYVAR` would be `undefined`

Comment: `MYVAR=something && npx webpack && node index.js` <- this does not set an environment variable. `MYVAR=something` should prepend **EVERY COMMAND** explicitly you want to set an environment variable for. Eg: `npx webpack && MYVAR=something node index.js`. Otherwise you can `export MYVAR=something` it first.

Comment: Sorry about the syntax, it wasn't accurate. My point was that explicitly setting an environment variable in the shell and running the application will prove to show no variables. Try it with the same application I provided and you'll see what I mean

Answer (score 0):

you have to inject environment variables into your project by using npm package. [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) is the most popular one. all you have to do, in the root directory of your project, which is where your package.json is, create `.env` file and add your env varibles like this:

```
DB_URL=DB_URI=mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/myDb // without strings
```

then in package.json inject the variables with a script:

```
      "dev": "nodemon --watch dist --exec  \"node -r dotenv/config dist/bundle.js\"",
```

Answer (score -3):

I re-read the title, and I guess your problem is that process.env is empty. Am I right? In that case, this is how you add environmental variables.

```
process.env.someVariable = "some variable";
console.log(process.env);
```

If that's not your question, would you specify what is expected result.

Also, you can store your environmental variables in .env file that must be placed in root directory of your project. To access them you can use dotenv npm package.